# Could not find table 'projects_users'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I accidentally named one of the models in plural, so I changed the name both manually:

```
projects_users.rb -> projects_user.rb
```

...and...

```
class ProjectsUsers < ActiveRecord::Base   ->    class ProjectsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
```

...and the table name with migration.

.

Now I get an error telling me:

```
Could not find table 'projects_users'
```

This is strange, because this is the old name of the database, and I can't find any place in my code where I refer to this name.

The controller that uses the table projects_user is the project controller and the error refers to the following (line 3):

```
1.   def edit
2.     @project = Project.find(params[:id])
3.     @members = ProjectsUser.where(:project_id => params[:id])
4.   end
```

What can be wrong? Where should I look?

Schema.rb is correct from what I can tell regarding this table:

```
create_table "projects_user", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "project_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
end

add_index "projects_user", ["project_id", "user_id"], :name => "index_projects_users_on_project_id_and_user_id"
```

Comment: Do you also updated migration and rerun it? Because it holds actual name of table.

Comment: I created a new migration file for the name change and run rake db:migrate, which changed the name (if this is what you mean?)

Comment: I don't know which table is created when naming is in plural, but after change model you also need to updated table to correct plural.

Comment: Just do `rake db:rollback` if it was the last migration. And delete the migration file.

Comment: By default Rails, if you have a `Project` model and a `User` model and you wanted a join model called `ProjectUser` then the table would be called `projects_users`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your models should be the singular form, but your database table should still be plural. Your schema indicates the database table will be singular (`projects_user`).

So a `ProjectsUser` model should have a corresponding `projects_users` table in your database.

Comment: Confusing, but now I understand. Thanks, it solved my problem :)

Comment: Think of it in this sense: An instance of your model represent a single object (A user) and your table is a collection of those objects (Users).